# Jquery list drag drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery Drag Drop List which I want to update immediately in MYSQL using Jquery Ajax Post.

Because I can drag elements between lists (more than one list), I need to get the parent ID (parent being list category ID - where the draggable is dragged to)

When I drag from one category / list to another I am always given the former ID..

For example:

CAT 1 ------------ CAT 2

If I was to drag something from CAT1 to CAT2 - the ID would be CAT1 and not the new category ID...

I have added my codes below:

**Jquery:**

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.sortable.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();
    });
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mouseup").mouseleave(function(){
    var sparent = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    alert(sparent);
    });
    });
    </script>
```

**LIST HTML:**

```
<div class="demo">
<div class="box">
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default mouseup">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default mouseup">Item 2</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="box">
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight mouseup">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight mouseup">Item 2</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: post the actual drag and drop code you are using, is it jquery++ or jquery.ui ?

Comment: updated - hope that is what you were asking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#events

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    stop: function(event, ui) { alert($(ui.item).parent().attr("id") }
}).disableSelection();
```

Placing your code in the stop callback will allow you check the right ID.

Comment: Thank you - you forgot to close the alert but not to worry I found that error myself - thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Event that you need to handle is `received`.

```
 $(".connectedSortable" ).on( "sortreceive", function(event, ui) { 
     alert(ui.item.parent()[0].id); 
     // also ui.sender will hold original list, from where element was taken
 });
```

EDITED: depending on the fact if you need to handle case when items were just reordered, ie you drag and drop within same list, or not you are going to use `received` or `stop` event.
`received` will fire only in case you drag to another list.
`stop` will fire even if you leave item in the same list.

Comment: is that the exact code I would add or would selector change to the mouseup class I currently have on my draggables?